# can not use Closure right

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote JS function and it must bind the buttons it generates depending on values in the array.
But it gives me the last value. I read that i had to use closure, I did, and I'm still not able to bind them right!
I'm still a beginner 
I read about closure, I got the idea but still did not know what I'm missing

```
function addNewServices(newServicesArray){
    var j=0; var x;
    for (i in newServicesArray){
        var html='';

        html='<div style="width: 33%; float: leftt"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="home" id="btn-'+newServicesArray[j].servicename+'" value="'+newServicesArray[j].servicename+'" class="ui-btn-up-c">'+newServicesArray[j].servicename+'</a></div>';
        $("#main-menu").append(html);


        $('#btn-'+newServicesArray[j].servicename).bind('click', function (){bindThis(j)});
        j++;
    }

    var bindThis = function( j ) {
        return function() {
            alert(j); // gives 2 always
            alert( newServicesArray[j].servicename ); 
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Use jQuery's `$.each` to iterate, it'll be easier...

Comment: You  should not declare `bindThis` inside the loop. Why do you declare x and never make use of it?

Comment: @fragmentedreality actually, bindThis is *not* declared inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to bind click in a loop... you can get the clicked refrence  by `$(this)` in a function..

making it as simple as i can..

```
function addNewServices(newServicesArray){
   var j=0; 
   for (i in newServicesArray){
      var html='';

      html='<div style="width: 33%; float: left"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="home" id="btn-'+newServicesArray[j].servicename+'" value="'+newServicesArray[j].servicename+'" class="ui-btn-up-c">'+newServicesArray[j].servicename+'</a></div>';

      $("#main-menu").append(html);


   }
}

$(function(){
  $(document).on('click','a[id^="btn-"]',function (){
      var $this = $(this);
      alert($this.attr('value')); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have

```
function (){bindThis(j)}
```

Which gets called later when the value of j is 2.

You only need

```
bindThis(j)
```

which gets called with the different values

Answer (score 1):

Closure is just the way function accesses variable from outer scope. The key word here is *variable* — variable may change, and if you access it afterwards (on click), you will access the later version of it.

So anyhow you need to store that association of `j` with `j`th button. Thanks to jQuery, `bind` method already have a facility just for this: its [second parameter](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), `eventData`, is some user data that will be passed to event handler function.

So, changing this:

```
(..).bind('click',function (){bindThis(j)});
```

to this:

```
(..).bind('click', j, bindThis);
```

...should* work. Note that we don't need to create any wrapper-function. We simply pass `bindThis` function itself to `bind`, and tell `bind` that it will pass `j` to it when calling it.

(*) — not tested yet